# How to group different elements in a column?

Tags: r

I would like to combine the classifications "married" and "together but not married" into a classification called "together" and have it still under the marital status column. I would also like to to that for the "divorced" and "widowed" classifications and call it "separate". So instead of the 4 different classifications under the marital status column, there would only be 2. How would I do this?

```
aggregate(. ~ "Married" + "Together but not married", data = Marital_Mental_Physical_noNA)
```

This is what I have tried with no luck.

| Marital Status | Mental Health Rating | Physical Health Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Married | 3 | 4 |
| Married | 24 | 5 |
| Together but not married | 4 | 4 |
| Together but not married | 14 | 34 |
| Divorced | 3 | 12 |
| Divorced | 22 | 42 |
| Divorced | 33 | 21 |
| Widowed | 23 | 22 |
| Widowed | 14 | 5 |
| Widowed | 17 | 4 |

Comment: Please share your current attempt at doing it. we do not have access to your actual data objects so cannot see how they are set up. Without you providing a [mre] we will not be able to help. Currently this seems like a maths question as you have not provided a way for us to do this programatically. Please read [ask] and add more details by making an [edit] to your question

Comment: I edited my original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case_when` from "dplyr":

```
x <- data.frame(Marital_Status = c("Married", "Together but not married", 
                                   "Divorced", "Widowed"))

library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  mutate(classification = case_when(
    Marital_Status %in% c("Widowed", "Divorced") ~ "separated", 
    Marital_Status %in% c("Married", "Together but not married") ~ "together"))
#             Marital_Status classification
# 1                  Married       together
# 2 Together but not married       together
# 3                 Divorced      separated
# 4                  Widowed      separated
```

You can also use [`Factor`](http://mrdwab.github.io/SOfun/reference/Factor.html) from [my "SOfun" package](http://mrdwab.github.io/SOfun/index.html):

```
library(SOfun)
Factor(x$Marital_Status, 
       list(together = c("Married", "Together but not married"), 
            separated = c("Divorced", "Widowed")), store = FALSE)
# [1] together  together  separated separated
# Levels: together separated
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `recode` from `car` package:

```
string <- 'c("Married", "Together but not married") = "together";
           c("Widowed", "Divorced") = "separated"'

x$new <- car::recode(Marital_Status, string)
x

            Marital_Status       new
1                  Married  together
2 Together but not married  together
3                 Divorced separated
4                  Widowed separated
```